# asp mvc Unique User ID for Temporary SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

What I would like to do is give the user a temporary database table that they save to as they fill out a form(to save their changes between requests). I was wondering the best way to do this. Currently I am doing the following:

```
Random rand = new Random(2000000);


object UserID = Session["TestID"];
if (UserID == null)
{
    // Session["TestID"] = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
    UserID = rand.Next();
    Session["TestID"] = UserID;
}
else
{
     UserID = Session["TestID"];
}
```

And creating tables with this UserID in the database, but I am 99% sure this is bad. Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I am just trying to save the changes a user makes to a form to a temporary table so that they can jump back and forth between pages and still keep their information. I figured the only way to do this was create a table with a unique id for the user that stores their temporary form data until they are ready to submit a final version. Is this not a good way to store data between requests?

Comment: I don't understand what the above has to do with database tables?

Comment: please add some more code that tells what you are going to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GUID. This is "almost" unique. Random could result in same value twice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Comment: hate to be pedantic but GUIDs are not *guaranteed to be unique* now the chances of them not being unique are pretty small but still....

Answer (score 0):

Is the schema the same for each table?  If so, then why not use the same table for all users?  You could use the user's session ID as the key.

Comment: The schema is not the same. I was thinking I could have a TempUserID variable in each table so I can keep track of the temporary tables users have created.